# Startup form in VB.NET keeps reseting to Form1 even if I change it in projet properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

All questions related to this issue simply answer "right click projet, properties, change startup form to the one you want". Which I did. However it doesn't update it in the autogenerated code in Application.Designer.vb. The only way I can run the application is by changing manually in that file the "form1" to the name of my main form, which will obviously get overridden as soon as I touch anything.

The property for startup form stays correct, with my own form selected even when the written code gets overriden.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET 5.0 with no unusual plugins

Answer (score 1):

You can change the startup form name in the `Application.myapp` file.
If you turn on `Show All Files`, you can see it as a part of `My Project`.
Or you go in explorer to the `My Project` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly as you said: "Right click project, properties, change startup form to the one you want". It has nothing to do with autogenerated code. `Application.Designer.vb` sounds very much like C# that was converted to VB. Just delete `Application.vb` and `Application.Designer.vb`, in VB it is not needed. (Or keep it, but then you have to point the startup to `Application` instead of a form.)

Comment: Unfortunately I had done that already. I found no way to fix the bug per say, i ended up renaming the form to the default "Form1" name as it kept being autogenerated that way even with the fresh name selected in properties.

However you do help me telling me I don't need to keep that ApplicationEvent.vb file. From now on I will simply make my own main module and generate my main form from there, and flush this automatic nonsense

Comment: This really is not an answer. I have the same issue and "resolved it" as did the OP by renaming the Form back to Form1.

Comment: This is not an answer and is unhelpful to boot.

The code is generated by whatever is generating the "MY" space in VB.net projects, for debugging. I have to keep changing the same line as well.